# IE7-8: 'clear' button with same height as input type="file" 'browse' button

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Here is my test (stripped down to minimum)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <style type="text/css">
        .file-form-active-inputs { margin-left : 2px; } 
    </style>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="file" name="_206_0_100070" size="60" id="HASH(0x331b400)" class="form-active-inputs">  
      <button class="file-form-active-inputs">
        Button with same height as 'browse' button to the left
      </button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to match button height

to a IE7-8  input type="file" "browse" button height?

Comment: Of course, I don't want not to restyle entire upload control, but use some IE-specific css hack to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you just want to make sure that the buttons match, one possible hackish way to do this is instead of trying to match the height of your clear button to the File Upload button, you style the File Upload button to match that of the clear button. The following [Trick](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) shows you how to do this using CSS or Javascript.

If you decide to follow this approach I would recommend that you do it with Javascript, because it allows you to have clean markup for all other browsers, but add in the additional elements only for IE.

Hopefully someone has some simple CSS to do what you are originally asking for rather than having to follow this technique, since it involves more work.

Good Luck

Comment: I did my search and seen this article. And yes, since this is  separate code branch for IE and not public site, I am just looking for this IE-specific css hack